# To have two limits in double integral?

Tags: math-mode

My tex

```
\begin{equation}
 \iint \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} 
\end{equation}
```

It looks like

[image]

I want two limits there above and below.

**How can you have two limits above and below the two integrals?**

Comment: How 'bout just using `\int` twice?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are probably expecting iterated integral, not double integral. Hence

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 

\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}

\begin{equation}
\Int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y) \,dx\,dy
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The multiple integral macros by `amsmath` only support lower limits on multiple integrals.

You can get around this by using a specialized font for integrals, like the one provided by `esint`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}

\makeatletter
%% make esint definition in line with amsmath
\@for\next:={int,iint,iiint,iiiint,dotsint,oint,oiint,sqint,sqiint,
  ointctrclockwise,ointclockwise,varointclockwise,varointctrclockwise,
  fint,varoiint,landupint,landdownint}\do{%
    \expandafter\edef\csname\next\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\DOTSI
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname\next op\endcsname
      \noexpand\ilimits@
    }%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 \iint \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice idea!

Answer (score 3):

Here comes a possible solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newlength\tmp@\newlength\t@mp
\newcommand{\comp}[3]
  {\mathop{ \settowidth\tmp@{$\displaystyle\mathop{#1}^{#3}_{#2}$}
  \hbox to \tmp@{\hss \settowidth\t@mp{$\displaystyle #1$}\setlength\t@mp{.45\t@mp}
  $\displaystyle\mathop{#1}^{\hspace\t@mp #3}_{\hspace{-\t@mp}#2}$
  \hss} }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
  &\comp{\int}{A}{B}+\int\\
  &\intop_A^B+\intop\\
  &\intop+\intop\\
  &\comp{\int}{AAA}{BBB}+\int\\
  &\intop_{AAA}^{BBB}+\int\\
  &\comp{\int}{AAAAAAAAA}{BBBBBBBBB}+\int\\
  &\intop_{AAAAAAAAA}^{BBBBBBBBB}+\int\\
\end{aligned}
%
\begin{aligned}
  &\comp{\int}{A}{B}\intop_{A}^{B}\\
  &\comp{\int}{AAA}{\rule{1cm}{10cm}}\intop_{AAA}^{\rule{1cm}{10cm}}\\
  &\comp{\int}{AAAAAAAAA}{BBBBBBBBB}\intop_{AAAAAAAAA}^{BBBBBBBBB}\\
%
  &\comp{\iint}{A}{B}\iint\limits_{A}^{B}\iint\\
  &\comp{\iint}{AAA}{BBB}\quad\iint\limits_{AAA}^{BBB}\iint
  \comp{\iint}{-\infty}{+\infty}\\
  &\comp{\iint}{AAAAAAAAA}{BBBBBBBBB}\quad\iint\limits_{AAAAAAAAA}^{BBBBBBBBB}\iint\\
%
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If you indent lines of code by four spaces -- most easily done by highlighting the rows in question and clicking o the `{}` "button" in the row above the edit window -- the site's software will pretty-print the code automatically. (Backticks should be used only for inline code snippets.)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to make it minimally compilable. Providing fully compilable examples rather than code snippets that make you guess which packages might have to be loaded (here: the `amsmath` package for the `\iint` macro) can be a frustrating exercise, the more so if the reader isn't an experienced LaTeX user.

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of `\rlap`?

Comment: @Masir I just use it to create the superscript `+\infty`. What `\rlap` contains is actually hidden. But I'm not sure if it works on your system since I didn't get a correct result as expected.