# How to code Triple Integral Bounds

Tags: integral

```
$$ \iiint \limits_0^{A} 1\,d\rho\,d\theta\,d\phi $$
```

[image]

The first integral is supposed to go from 0 to A, then second is from 0 to pi, and the third should be from 0 to 1. I couldn't find anything about it online.

Comment: The usual approach would be three different `\int`, each with their own limits.  `\iiint` would have the limits too bunched up to tell apart, in my opinion.  Are you sure you want that?  (PS, you should use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/107497)

Answer (score 3):

Since you appear to prefer placing the limits of integration above and below the integral symbols, I would like to recommend that you "snug up" the integral symbols by inserting `\!\!` (double negative thinspace) between them.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\int_{0}^{A} \!\! \int_{0}^{\pi} \!\! \int_{0}^{1} \!   d\rho \, d\theta \, d\phi
\qquad
\int_{0}^{A} \!\! \int_{0}^{\pi} \!\! \int_{0}^{1} 1 \, d\rho \, d\theta \, d\phi
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Plus, if it blends with your discipline, a differential operator set upright (e.g. [here on tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60545/should-i-mathrm-the-d-in-my-integrals)).

Comment: @Buttonwood - Thanks. Since the query was (mainly? exclusively?) about how to place the three pairs of limits of integration, I decided not to modify the OP's code for the differential operators.

Comment: I don't see it as an error. Like setting variables italic or upright shows depends on convention (and varies locally), the comment was about an optional «if».

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of `\limits` with `\int`, unless one wants to just set a domain.

Here's a simplified version, as regards to user level syntax, that automatically computes the number of integral signs to use, based on the list of bounds.

I provide `\INT` for limits on the side and `\INT*` for limits above and below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\INT}{sm}
 {
  \kourosh_int:een
   { \IfBooleanT{#1}{\limits} } % \limits for *-version
   { \IfBooleanTF{#1}{6}{9} }   % less kerning for *-version
   { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_kourosh_int_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l_kourosh_int_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kourosh_int:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_kourosh_int_in_seq { #3 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_kourosh_int_out_seq \l_kourosh_int_in_seq { \int#1 ##1 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_kourosh_int_out_seq { \mspace{-#2mu} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \kourosh_int:nnn { ee }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\INT{_0^A,_0^\pi,_0^1} 1\,d\rho\,d\theta\,d\phi
\]
\[
\INT*{_0^A,_0^\pi,_0^1} 1\,d\rho\,d\theta\,d\phi
\]
\[
\INT{_0^\pi,_0^1} 1\,d\theta\,d\phi
\]
\[
\INT{_0^1} 1\,d\phi
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a triple integral with bounds I would be more inclined to write

```
\[
  \int_{0}^{A}  
  \int_{0}^{\pi}
  \int_{0}^{1}
     1\,d\rho\,d\theta\,d\phi
\]
```

limits style is going to push your limits too close together. It makes more sense if you have something like

```
\[
   \iiint\limits_{(x,y,z)\in U^3} f(x,y,z) dx\, dy\, dz
\]
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment came in before I could post..

Yea, that's the answer:

See also:  [To have two limits in double integral?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148520/to-have-two-limits-in-double-integral)

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}
\begin{document}

$$\Int_{0}^{A} \Int_{0}^{\pi} \Int_{0}^{1} d\rho\; d\theta\; d\phi$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would use thinspace (`\,`), not thickspace (`\;`), between the dummy variables of integration.

Comment: Alright thanks it worked now!